# Is okay to useMemo instead of useEffect for calling side-effect functions

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Let's have a Component with take <count: number> props. Inside of that component, I call a side-effect and it should only call when props.count change (1 -> 1 shouldn't count as a change). Is it okay to use useMemo in this way?

```js
  useMemo(() => {
    callAPI();
  }, [count]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

You should use `useEffect` hook for side-effects.

`useMemo` returns a memoized value.

```
const memoizedValue = useMemo(() => computeExpensiveValue(a, b), [a, b]);
```

You should not cause any side effect in `useMemo`.

For more on this you can read here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

Answer (score 4):

I'd say you *could* use `useMemo` for side-effects. It's one of your options if you want to execute some code on prop change BEFORE the first render with the new prop value completes - there might be situations when it's necessary.

The only reason you should *not* use `useMemo` is this one small comment in the official React doc:

> You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee. **In the future, React may choose to “forget” some previously memoized values and recalculate them on next render**, e.g. to free memory for offscreen components. Write your code so that it still works without useMemo — and then add it to optimize performance.

So instead, you could implement your own hook that fires up **before** the results of rerender apply to the page. I wrote mine along these lines:

```
export const usePreEffect = (func: () => void, deps: unknown[]) => {
  const lastDeps = useRef<unknown[]>();
  if (!shallowEqual(deps, lastDeps.current)) {
    func();
  }
  lastDeps.current = deps;
};
```

and then

```
  usePreEffect(() => {
    // ...do your specific stuff here, like checking the prev state of the DOM
  }, [prop.value]);
```

Note, the body of that *pre-effect* executes in the scope of the render function itself, thus you should NOT be setting state synchronously from there. But you could do a few tricks to make it work, like the use of `setTimeout(...)`.

Comment: I tried to replace 2 instances in my code which used `useMemo` for running before render with your `usePreEffect` hook, and it didn't work. the code ran after render so I had to switch back to useMemo.

Comment: That's hardly possible, unless your `shallowEqual` implementation and lack of provided dependencies caused that. The code above is very simple and straightforward, no magic there.

Comment: that's very possible, as I copied and pasted your code AS-IS and switched a few times from useMemo to usePreEffect back and forth to make sure. the shallowEqual implementation is from react-redux, version 8.0.5. checked in yarn.lock